# Group Outlook tasks by due-date categories: "Today," "Tomorrow," "This Week," "Next Week," etc

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, sorting, date, tasks

I use Outlook's Task "peek" to organize my to-do list. When I let Outlook "Automatically group [tasks] according to arrangement," as in this picture—

[image]

—it groups them by the categories "Today," "Tomorrow," "This Week," "Next Week," etc. I like this grouping. But I find that I can use it only when I sort tasks by a single field (in my case, "Due Date"). If I instead try to sort by both "Due Date" and (say) "Subject," I lose this nice automatic grouping into date categories. How can I retain this grouping while still sorting according to multiple fields?

Explicitly grouping by the "Due Date" field is not an option. Doing that will give me a distinct group for each date, and that isn't what I want.

One possibility is that the "Automatically group according to arrangement" option is simply grouping by some kind of "date category" field. If I find that field, I can then stop automatic grouping, start explicitly grouping by that field, and then (I think) sort according to whichever fields I choose. But is there a "date category" field in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the task grouped as shown in the below figure?

[image]

If so, you just need to refer to the below steps:

1.Click the **Arrange by** on the top of the list of tasks, and then click **View Settings…**

[image]

2.Click **Group by…**>unselect "Automatically group according to arrangement". And choose the two options as shown in the below figure.

[image]

3.Click OK.

Hope to help you!

Comment: Thank you, Christy—but that's not quite what I'm looking for. The solution that you've offered groups tasks first by due *day*: tasks for August 23rd, followed by August 24th, followed by August 25th, and so on. But I don't want tasks to be grouped by day—not to that extent. Instead, I want the groupings to be "Today," "Tomorrow," "This Week," "Next Week," and so on. We can get these groupings if we select the "Automatically group according to arrangement" option in your 2nd screenshot. But I don't know how to have that grouping while sorting within each group by both "Due Date" and "Subject".

Comment: Hi @user697473! If you want to group it both by date and subject, i'm afraid that only the above is available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

- Right click on Columns >> View Settings
- Click on Group By.. make sure it is : none for all
- Check(tick) Automatically group according to arrangement
- Click OK
- Then Click on Sort..
- Sort items by Due Date Ascending.
- Click OK
- Click on Filter >> Advanced
- Choose field Date Completed : does not exist.
- Click add to list.
- Choose Complete : equals : no.
- Click add to list.
- Click OK.

And now you will have Today, Tomorrow, Next week ect. in Outlook task view.

Comment: Thank you, Triacona. But this isn't what I'm looking for. As I wrote in my original post, I already have "Today, Tomorrow, Next week ect. in Outlook task view." What I want is to preserve that grouping while also sorting within each group by both Due Date and Subject.